# Highcharts setOptions with multiple yAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highchart with setOptions to globally configure the charts. When creating a new chart, the yAxis property can be an array in case of multiple yAxis.

This does not work for setOptions(). When I put there an array as mutliple yAxis the theming isn't taken.

Is there any work around for this ugly issue?

Comment: Hi, can you provide jsfiddle link ?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d43rk251/7/) I have not added a second one only changed to have one yAxis but the style isnt taken how it should. I expect the first yAxis label on the top left to appear, when you change from array to object you will see that is changed and working, but not with array.

Comment: I think that the purpose of setOptions is to set general options - so in setOptions you should not use specific options for a specific axis (array usage) but instead use an object - and in chart's options set options which refers to a specific axis. http://jsfiddle.net/d43rk251/11/